# File IO using java

Tags: java, file-io, input, io

I am new to java and using netbeans v8. I am trying to read strings from a file and saving modifications in a new file but when I run the code it does not show anything it continues running. 
code is

```
package filereadingandwriting;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReadingAndWriting {
    public static void readAndWrite() throws Exception
    {
        File inputFile = new File("names.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File outFile = new File("output.txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        for(int i = 0;input.hasNextLine(); i++)
        {
            String inputLines = input.nextLine();
            writer.println("Sr#" + i + " " + inputLines);
    }

    input.close();
} // readAndWrite function ends.
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    readAndWrite();
} // main function ends.

} //FileReadingAnd Writing class ends.
```

Comment: It seems like you are not reading from the inputFile, instead you are reading from System.in...

Comment: Please note that java.io.File is considered legacy API. Consider to use the NIO.2 File API instead. Here is the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: Also consider to use try-with-resources to close your input- and output file.

Comment: @Puce Considered legacy APi by whom? Not by the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP It's considered legacy API by Oracle's tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html Indeed, the "Legacy File I/O Code" section seems to be the only place where java.io.File is still mentioned. So like Vector, Hashtable, java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar (to name a few), also java.io.File has been superseded by a new API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read from your inputFile you have to change your code to:

```
File inputFile = new File("names.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
```

In your case you would read from STDIN.

Also you should use the newer `java.nio.*` API

Answer (score 0):

Just change `new Scanner(System.in);` to `new Scanner(inputFile);`.

Comment: Now it is showing error that names.txt file is not found.
I have placed names.txt file in the same directory as of java file.

Comment: @Talha You need to put it elsewhere, there should be many answers on this on SO.